# Error in converting string to float

Tags: c#, regex

I have a rookie's question about the conversion.

```
string Descript1 = ":1:2:3:4:5";
Regex pattern = new Regex("(:)");

foreach (string sub in pattern.Split(Descript1))
{
    if (sub != ":")
    {
        float a = Convert.ToSingle(sub);
    }
}
```

But this code keep pumping out the error: "the string was not in the correct format.".

Anyone could help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this in any particular programming language?

Comment: is the extra " in string Descript1 = ":1:2:3:4:5""; a typo?

Answer (score 7):

The first result of the split is an empty string, i.e. what's before the first colon in the string.

Skip empty strings instead of skipping ":" (as that never can appear in the result):

```
string Descript1 = ":1:2:3:4:5";
Regex pattern = new Regex(":");

foreach (string sub in pattern.Split(Descript1)) {
  if (sub.Length > 0) {
    Single a = Convert.ToSingle(sub);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need the regex pattern.  The [`Split`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx) method has an overload that accepts your delimiter as a string.

Do a console.writeline (or breakpoint), and make sure you are getting a string that makes sense for the conversion.

Answer (score 2):

I'd imagine your array would begin with an empty string (because of the : at the beginning of your string).  Step one is to use a debugger to figure out whether the array contains what you think it contains.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sub != ":" && sub!="")
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string description = ":1:2:3:4:5";
var floats = from part in description.Split(new char[] { ':' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
             select float.Parse(part);
foreach (var f in floats)
{
    Console.WriteLine(f);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex.Split is returning a empty string at the beginning of your array (returned from Pattern.Split)

Change it to the following and it should work:

```
string Descript1 = ":1:2:3:4:5";
Regex pattern = new Regex("(:)");

foreach (string sub in pattern.Split(Descript1))
{
    if (sub != ":" && sub != string.Empty)
    {

        float a = float.Parse(sub);
    }
}
```